# python/Kivy : How to pass value of textbox in new window

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I have two file `demo.py` and `demo.kv`.
When i run `demo.py` and click on `+Add` then screen shows looks like.I want value of `name` textbox in `def add_row(self):` function when click on `button`.When i click on button of first row then i want to get `test1`  in  `def add_row(self):` which are in `class RowsExtra(BoxLayout):` and click on button of second row then get `test2`.I want to get `test1` value in `textName` variable.After that i am fetching data from database according `name` textbox value.

```
def add_row(self):
    print("here,i want value of name(`test1`) when click on button")
    textName = 'test1'
    #cur.execute("SELECT `column_name` FROM `table_name` WHERE `name`=?", (textName,))
    #rows = cur.fetchone()
    rows = [('A1'), ('B1'), ('C1'), ('D1')]
    for row in rows:
        self.row_count += 1
        r = RowExtra(button_text=str(self.row_count))
        r.col_data[1] = row

        self.add_widget(r)
```

## demo.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ListProperty, StringProperty, ObjectProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

Window.clearcolor = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
Window.size = (500, 400)

class User(Popup):
    total_value = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(User, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def add_more(self):
        self.ids.rows.add_more()

class ExtraPopup(Popup):
    mode = StringProperty("")

    def __init__(self, obj, **kwargs):
        super(ExtraPopup, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def add_extra(self):
        self.ids.rowsExtra.add_row()


class RowExtra(BoxLayout):
    col_data = ListProperty(["?", "?", "?", "?", "?", "?", "?", "?"])
    button_text = StringProperty("")
    mode = StringProperty("")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RowExtra, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.col_data[0] = ''
        self.col_data[1] = ''
        self.col_data[2] = ''


class RowsExtra(BoxLayout):
    #orientation = "vertical"
    row_count = 0
    button_text = StringProperty("")


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RowsExtra, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_row()

    def add_row(self):
        print("here,i want value of name(`test1`) when click on button")
        textName = 'test1'
        #cur.execute("SELECT `column_name` FROM `table_name` WHERE `name`=?", (textName,))
        #rows = cur.fetchone()
        rows = [('A1'), ('B1'), ('C1'), ('D1')]
        for row in rows:
            self.row_count += 1
            r = RowExtra(button_text=str(self.row_count))
            r.col_data[1] = row

            self.add_widget(r)



class Row(BoxLayout):
    col_data = ListProperty(["?", "?", "?", "?", "?"])
    name = ObjectProperty(None)
    button_text = StringProperty("")
    col_data3 = StringProperty("")
    col_data4 = StringProperty("")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Row, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def add_seller_expenses(self):
        self.mode = "Add"
        popup = ExtraPopup(self)
        popup.open()


class Rows(BoxLayout):
    row_count = 0

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Rows, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_more()

    def add_more(self):
        self.row_count += 1
        self.add_widget(Row(button_text=str(self.row_count)))


class rv(BoxLayout):
    data_items = ListProperty([])
    mode = StringProperty("")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(rv, self).__init__(**kwargs)


    def add(self):
        self.mode = "Add"
        popup = User()
        popup.open()


class MainMenu(BoxLayout):
    content_area = ObjectProperty()

    def display(self):
        self.rv = rv()
        self.content_area.add_widget(self.rv)

class demo(App):

    def build(self):
        return MainMenu()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    demo().run()
```

## demo.kv

```
<Row>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
    height: 40

    Button:
        text: root.button_text
        size_hint_x: None
        top: 200

    TextInput:
        id : name
        text: root.col_data3
        width: 300
    TextInput:
        id: number_input
        text: root.col_data4
        width: 300
        input_filter: 'int'

    Button:
        text: "Button"
        size_hint_x: None
        top: 200
        on_press: root.add_seller_expenses()


<Rows>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
    orientation: "vertical"

<User>:
    id: user
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding : 20, 5


        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            #padding : 10, 10
            spacing: 10, 10
            size: 450, 40
            size_hint: None, None

            Label:
                size_hint_x: .2
                text: "Number"
                text_size: self.size
                valign: 'bottom'
                halign: 'center'

            Label:
                size_hint_x: .4
                text: "name"
                text_size: self.size
                valign: 'bottom'
                halign: 'center'

            Label:
                size_hint_x: .4
                text: "Value"
                text_size: self.size
                valign: 'bottom'
                halign: 'center'




        ScrollView:
            Rows:
                id: rows


        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint_x: .2
            size_hint_y: .2

            Button:
                text: "+Add More"
                on_press: root.add_more()

<rv>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        Button:
            size_hint: .25, .03
            text: "+Add"
            on_press: root.add()

        GridLayout:
            size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 25
            cols: 3

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"

<ExtraPopup>:
    title: " Extra"
    title_size: 20
    title_font: "Verdana"
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400, 400
    auto_dismiss: False


    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding : 10, 5
        spacing: 10, 10

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            spacing: 10, 10
            size: 550, 30
            size_hint: 1, None

            Label:
                size_hint_x: .3
                text: "SN"
                text_size: self.size
                valign: 'bottom'
                halign: 'center'

            Label:
                size_hint_x: .7
                text: "Name"
                text_size: self.size
                valign: 'bottom'
                halign: 'center'

        ScrollView:
            RowsExtra:
                id: rowsExtra

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint_x: .3
            size_hint: .15, .1

            Button:
                #size_hint_x: .2
                text: "+Add More"
                valign: 'bottom'
                on_press: root.add_extra()



        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            padding : 10, 5
            spacing: 10, 10
            size_hint: .5, .2
            pos_hint: {'x': .25, 'y':.25}
            Button:
                text: 'Ok'
                id: ok_text
                on_release:
                    root.dismiss()

            Button:
                text: 'Cancel'
                #size_hint_x: .5
                on_release: root.dismiss()

<RowExtra>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
    height: 30

    Button:
        text: root.button_text
        size_hint_x: .3
        #top: 200

    TextInput:
        text: root.col_data[1]
        size_hint_x: .7



<RowsExtra>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
    orientation: "vertical"

<MenuButton@Button>:
    text_size: self.size
    valign: "middle"
    padding_x: 5
    size : (100, 40)
    size_hint : (None, None)
    background_color: 90 , 90, 90, 90
    background_normal: ''
    color: 0, 0.517, 0.705, 1
    border: (0, 10, 0, 0)

<MainMenu>:
    content_area: content_area

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing : 10

        BoxLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

            size_hint_y: 2

            MenuButton:
                text: 'Menu'
                size : (50, 12)
                on_release: root.display()

        BoxLayout:
            id: content_area
            size_hint_y: 30
```

Comment: You say: *i want to get test1*. My question is where do you want to get it?

Comment: @eyllanesc thanks.Sorry for inconvenience.I have updated code.Please can you take a look?

Comment: One query, within the second popup there is a `+Add More` button, that calls the add_row method of RowsExtra for second, third ... time, should the same textName be maintained?

Comment: @eyllanesc . If it happen third time then I want to get third row name textbox value.when click on button then I want to get name textbox value of same row

Comment: I think you have not understood me, first click, first press + Add, then we will have a 3 columns form: Number, Name, Value, then let's say that in the TextInput place "Hello" and then I press the Button, then it I will have another popup with 2 columns, that popup also has a button that is called `+ Add More` that calls again the add_row() function, my question is: does textName have to be "Hello" or will it vary?

Comment: I refer to the following image: https://imgur.com/a/icPJH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to access `rowsExtra` through the popup since it is your child, but one problem is that you call `add_row()` in the constructor before it is assigned a parent (the assignment of a parent is after the creation of the object), we must eliminate that instruction and call it again before opening the popup. To store the text we can create a property of type `StringProperty`.

```
[...]
class RowsExtra(BoxLayout):
    #orientation = "vertical"
    row_count = 0
    button_text = StringProperty("")
    textName = StringProperty("")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RowsExtra, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def add_row(self):
        print("here,i want value of name(`test1`) when click on button")
        print(self.textName)
        #cur.execute("SELECT `column_name` FROM `table_name` WHERE `name`=?", (textName,))
        #rows = cur.fetchone()
        rows = [('A1'), ('B1'), ('C1'), ('D1')]
        for row in rows:
            self.row_count += 1
            r = RowExtra(button_text=str(self.row_count))
            r.col_data[1] = row
            self.add_widget(r)

class Row(BoxLayout):
    col_data = ListProperty(["?", "?", "?", "?", "?"])
    name = ObjectProperty(None)
    button_text = StringProperty("")
    col_data3 = StringProperty("")
    col_data4 = StringProperty("")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Row, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def add_seller_expenses(self):
        self.mode = "Add"
        popup = ExtraPopup(self)
        popup.ids.rowsExtra.textName = self.ids.name.text
        popup.ids.rowsExtra.add_row()
        popup.open()
[...]
```

Comment: @Yash I recommend you to order your code in several files and try each functionality, now that your project has been extended, it is difficult to help you, so you probably can not do it anymore.